# Simplification of a definition in Hartshorne's algebraic geometry book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

I'm reading Hartshorne's book and on page 53 he defines intersection multiplicity of a projective variety and a hypersurface:

[image]

I'm wondering if we can simplify this definition if we take $Y$ to be a curve and $H$ to be an hyperplane.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: If $Y$ is a curve then you're calculating lengths which just happen to be $k$-dimensions, so things are indeed simpler.

Comment: @Hoot I couldn't redefine this definition in a simpler way. Could you help me, please? Thank you